# Unable to launch IIS Express Web server - Port '80' is in use

Tags: c#, iis, webserver, port, iis-express

I am getting error message stating Port 80 is in use for one project but not for the other few projects and they are set-up in the same way, but clearly something is different about the set-up of this project.

I have followed below links but nothing works:-

[unable to launch iis express web server port 80 is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163717/unable-to-launch-iis-express-web-server-port-80-is-in-use)

[Unable to launch the IIS express web server port 80 is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002582/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-port-80-is-in-use)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b694b04-60af-4ee8-b87b-1d9c3a9f70a6/unable-to-launch-iis-express-web-server-port-80-is-in-use?forum=aspgettingstarted

I have no idea what that is and would appreciate any guidance

[image: Error when running solution]

Comment: This should solve your problem: [How can you find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I undid my changes to the project, restarted my machine and got latest and it now works...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I undid my changes to the project, restarted my machine and got latest and it now works.